# How to specify column position using import-csv in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

As I have many csv files and want to sort first column of csv file, in that case first column name may differ for each file. Hence how to specify the column position for sort the many different files.
here is my script that I tried and am seeking like this code.($_.1)

```
$InputFilePath = "C\test.csv"
$OutputFolderPath ="C:\output.csv"
$UniqueValue = Import-Csv $InputFilePath  | Sort-Object -Property $_.1 | Export-Csv -Encoding Default -NoTypeInformation $OutputFolderPath
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

### Reflecting against `psobject` on each item

```
Import-Csv $InputFilePath |Sort-Object -Property { $_.psobject.Properties.Value[0] }
```

Here, we reference the hidden `psobject` memberset on each object to "discover" it's properties, and resolving the value of the first one.

### Extracting from the first row

```
$data = Import-Csv $InputFilePath
$sortKey = $data[0].psobject.Properties.Name[0]

$data |Sort-Object -Property $sortKey
```

Here we load all the data into a variable first, then discover the first property name of the very first object in the collection, and then use that property name to pass to `Sort-Object`

You may find this approach performs slightly better for medium-sized files (thousands of rows), but might allocate more memory as file size increases.

Test each against your data set and see what works best :-)

Answer (score 4):

You may do the following:

```
$InputFilePath = "C\test.csv"
$OutputFolderPath ="C:\output.csv"

Import-Csv $InputFilePath  | Sort-Object { $_.psobject.Properties.Value[0] } |
    Export-Csv -Encoding Default -NoTypeInformation $OutputFolderPath
```

Each object has a hidden `psobject` property, which is a type `PSMemberSet`. Its `Properties` property contains all the properties on your custom object in the order that they were deserialized. Since you want the first column's data for sorting, you can simply access its `Value` property. The first property will be index `[0]` of course.