# Why Import-Csv's Sort-Object is slow for 1 million records

Tags: powershell

I need to sort first column (column may differ) of csv files.
As my csv files have more than a million records, for executing below command , it is taking 10 minutes.

is there any other way to optimize the code to speed up the execution?

```
$CsvFile = "D:\Performance\10_lakh_records.csv"
$OutputFile ="D:\Performance\output.csv"

    Import-Csv $CsvFile  | Sort-Object { $_.psobject.Properties.Value[1] } | Export-Csv -Encoding default -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: How long does it take when you just do `Import-Csv $CsvFile | Export-Csv ...`? I. e. is it really `Sort-Object` that is the bottleneck here? Also, have you tried "extracting from the first row" method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65993113/7571258)? Should be slightly more efficient.

Comment: How much is `10Laks` ?

Comment: What happens if you just do `| Sort-Object` *<name of 1st column>* ?

Comment: Yes Bottleneck is Sort-Object. without sort-object execution has been completed in 40 seconds.

Comment: @Theo 1 Lak(h) is 10^5, so 10 = 1 million

Comment: Btw. if your `$CsvFile` file is actually headerless, you should use the `-Header` argument otherwise your first record will be missing (as it is presumed to be a header): e.g.: `Import-Csv $CsvFile -Header (1..5) | Sort-Object '2' | ...`

Comment: Csv files have headers,.

Comment: So, why are you using `$_.psobject.Properties.Value[1]` ([member enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12133329/1701026), which I suspect is more expensive) and not just the header name?

Comment: @iRon Perhaps because they have many different header formats across files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the `[array]::Sort()` static method which might prove faster than `Sort-Object`, although it does take an extra step to first get a one-dimensional array of all values to sort upon..

Try

```
$CsvFile    = "D:\Performance\10_lakh_records.csv"
$OutputFile = "D:\Performance\output.csv"

# import the data
$data = Import-Csv -Path $CsvFile

# determine the column name to sort on. In this demo the first column
# of course, if you know the column name you don't need that and can simply use the name as-is
$column = $data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[0]

# use the Sort(Array, Array) overload method to sort the data by the 
# values of the column you have chosen.
# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_
[array]::Sort($data.$column, $data)

$data | Export-Csv -Encoding default -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Yes , It is much faster than Sort-Object. half of the time of sort-object. Thanks.